# Lower bound for the sum of Bernoulli random variable

Tags: probability

this is an exercise 2.1.2. of Tao's random matrix theory book.
I am trying to solve by myself but I am stuck on this.

Here is the problem.
Let 0 < p < 1/2 be fixed independently of n, and let $X_1,\cdots, X_n$ be iid copies of a Bernouolli random variable that equals 1 with probability p, thus $\mu_i = p$ and $\sigma_i^2 = p(1-p)$, and so $\mu = np$ and $\sigma^2 = np(1-p)$.
Using Stirling's formula, show that
\begin{equation}
\textbf{P}(|S_n - \mu| \ge \lambda \sigma ) \ge c \exp(-C\lambda^2)
\end{equation}
for some absolute constants $C, c >0$ and all $\lambda \le c\sigma$.

Here are my approaches.

**Approach 1:** Since
\begin{equation}
\textbf{P}(|S_n - \mu| \ge \lambda \sigma ) 
= \textbf{P}(S_n \ge \mu + \lambda \sigma ) + \textbf{P}( -S_n \ge -\mu + \lambda \sigma ) 
\end{equation}
and $S_n$ and $-S_n$ have the same variance, it suffices to compute
\begin{equation}
\textbf{P}(S_n \ge \mu + \lambda \sigma )
\end{equation}
Let $m$ be the smallest integer greater or equal to $\mu + \lambda \sigma$. Then
\begin{equation}
\textbf{P}(S_n \ge \mu + \lambda \sigma ) = \sum_{k=m}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
\end{equation}
But from here, it is not clear how to deal with the summation and use the Stirling formula.

**Approach 2:** It suffices to show that
\begin{equation}
1 - \textbf{P}(|S_n - \mu| \ge \lambda \sigma ) 
= \textbf{P}(\mu - \lambda \sigma \le S_n \le \mu + \lambda \sigma )
\le 1 - c\exp(-C\lambda^2)
\end{equation}
Let $m_l$ be the biggest integer smaller or equal to $\mu - \lambda \sigma$
and $m_u$ be the smallest integer greater or equal to $\mu + \lambda \sigma$. Then
\begin{equation}
\textbf{P}(|S_n - \mu| < \lambda \sigma ) \le \sum_{k=m_l}^{m_u} \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
\end{equation}
It follows from page 3 in [Link](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~fan/complex/ch2.pdf) that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=m_l}^{m_u} \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
\approx \sum_{|k-\mu|\le \lambda \sigma} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp(-(k-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2)
\end{equation}
But I am not sure how to deduce $1 - c\exp(-C\lambda^2)$ out of it.

Any comments or answers will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach $2$ is nearly there:  Note that $$ \sum_{|k-\mu|\le \lambda \sigma} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp(-(k-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2) \xrightarrow{\sigma \to \infty} \int_{-\lambda}^\lambda \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2 / 2} \,dx$$
since the sum is the Riemann sum for the integral.   Deducing $1 - c\exp(-C \lambda^2)$ is just a matter of computing the tails of the Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I have a question. This argument uses when $n \to \infty$. I am not sure how this is connected to the upper bound. Also I am not sure when the condition of $\lambda \le c\sigma$ is used.

Comment: To be more precise, I think we might need the first inequality \begin{equation} \sum_{|k-\mu|\le \lambda \sigma} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp(-(k-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2) \le \int_{-\lambda}^\lambda \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2 / 2} \,dx \le 1 -
 2\exp(-\lambda^2/2) \end{equation} where the second inequality follows from the Chernoff bounds.